# Angularjs issue $http.get not loading image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to create an ionic application which uses a gallery. I'm unsure why my image isn't being loaded into the application.

What i'm trying to develop is an gallery which loads the images from a JSON file.

Here's my HTML

```
<ion-view view-title="Gallery" align-title="center">

<ion-content ng-controller="photoCtrl" ng-init="getImages()">
    <div class="row" ng-repeat="image in images" ng-if="$index % 4 === 0">
        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index < images.length">
            <img ng-src="{{data.images[$index].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index + 1 < images.length">
            <img ng-src="{{data.images[$index + 1].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index + 2 < images.length">
            <img ng-src="{{data.images[$index + 2].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
        <div class="col col-25" ng-if="$index + 3 < images.length">
            <img ng-src="{{data.images[$index + 3].src}}" width="100%" />
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Javascript:

```
.controller("photoCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.images = [];

    $scope.getImages = function() {
        $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/30vuu')
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.data = images;
            })
    }

});
```

I have also created a codepen: http://codepen.io/beefman/pen/eNMgzG

Comment: demo isn't returning an array of images, just an object with a property `images` that contains a string. Also in your `$http` callback you aren't doing anything with the response `data` so you are assigning `$scope.data` to empty array

Comment: html doesn't match data structure either

Comment: My Javascript should be $scope.images = data?   Also i'm unsure of why my html doesn't match data sctructure. When i use <div class="col col-25"><img ng-src="{{data.images}}" width="100%"/></div>.  It works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON API return an associative array (key-value pair) like this:

```
{"images":"http://mintywhite.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/fond-ecran-wallpaper-image-arriere-plan-hd-29-HD.jpg"}
```

but your template code expects an array (list):

```
data.images[$index].src
```

so I would start by matching your JSON with the format expected by your template.

Edit: Here's a JSON format that would match your template's expectations:

```
{'images': [{'src': 'url1'}, {'src': 'url2'}]}
```

Also, make sure to set the images variable properly in your callback

```
$scope.images = data.images
```

now $scope.images is a list of key value pairs

with ng-repeat you can display the images like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="image in images">
  <img ng-src="image.src" />
</div>
```

Comment: How do i change my JSON format to match my HTML?                        "photos":[
    {"images":"url"}
]      - something like that?      then in my html it would be photos.data.images?

Comment: Still can't get it to work. I've tried changing my json file by adding an array. In my HTML do i have to include the array? http://codepen.io/beefman/pen/eNMgzG

Comment: I see that the codepen is working now (sorta), do you still have issues?

Comment: Yes, for some reason the forth image isn't loading. No idea why. Something to do with my HTML i'm guessing. A part from that it is working. I've checked my JSON file and it's fine.

Comment: Fixed it now. Missing a }

Answer (score 1):

Your controller should be like this

```
.controller("photoCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.images = [];

    $scope.getImages = function() {
        $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/30vuu')
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.images = data;
            })
    }

});
```